# Service bus endpoints passing through load balancer

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, osb

I am using Service Bus 11gR1

I have created a proxy service
I can view it's WSDL if I point my browser to:
https://wlsdev.mydomain.com/osb/RJMTest/XXIC_ErrorQueryAsync_Proxy?wsdl

When I look at the returned WSDL I can see the binding element lists the actual host rather than the load balancer:

```
  </WL5G3N0:binding>
  <WL5G3N0:service name="query_ptBindingQSService">
    <WL5G3N0:port binding="WL5G3N2:query_ptBinding" name="query_ptBindingQSPort">
      <WL5G3N3:address location="http://internalserver.com:8010/osb/RJMTest/XXIC_ErrorQueryAsync_Proxy"/>
    </WL5G3N0:port>
  </WL5G3N0:service>
```

My question is what setting in OSB do I need to change to alter what the SOAP wsdl is using to generate the WSDL?

(In SOA there was a ServerURL setting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update the cluster http frontend host to the load balancer address. This will need to be done on WebLogic Admin console

1. Login to http://{host}:{port}/console
2. Clicked on Lock and Edit button
3. Select Cluster
4. Click on HTTP
5. Configure Front End Host address to the pool name of load balancer
6. Configure http and https port where managed servers listen to
7. Click Save.

You will need to restart the managed servers.